# Creating Subsets of data with multiple where/between statements

Tags: r

I have a dataset which consists of 2 days in 2 different months and the same time periods. It shows how many occupants were in a house during the time. I want to separate the data by date, time period AND houseid.

So i want to get all the records where the date is 01-02-2010, between the time periods 14:00:00 - 19:00:00 where houseid is N60421A. At the moment data.type is stored as characters except for occupants which is numeric.

http://www.sharecsv.com/s/aa6d4dc34acfbaf73ada1d2c8764b888/modecsv.csv

Atm i have tried this but i seem to get no results

```
data2 = subset(data, dayMonthYear == "01/02/2010" && Houses == "N60421A")
```

In SQL i would do something like

```
SELECT *
From data
where dayMonthYear == "01/02/2010"
AND houses == "N60421A"
AND time > 14:00:00
AND time < 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
#Combine date and time into a new POSIXct variable "Time1"
data$Time1 <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$dayMonthYear, data$Time), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

#Subset 
data2 <-subset(data, dayMonthYear == "01/02/2010" & Houses == "N60421A" & strftime(Time1, "%H") %in% c('14','15','16','17','18','19'))
```

You could also use the "chron" package and standard R subsetting...

```
#Approach 2
#Load Library
library(chron)

#Convert Time from factor while creating new variable "Time2"
data$Time2 <- chron(times = as.character(data$Time))

#Subset
data2 <- data[(data$dayMonthYear == "01/02/2010" & data$Houses == "N60421A" & data$Time2 >= "14:00:00" & data$Time2 <= "19:00:00" ),]
```

Comment: Time1 actually returns N/A when i look at the data table. Is there not a way to do this without combining the two?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you share your data with dput instead of providing the csv?

Comment: @KHAN I added a second approach that does not combine date and time.